# complete step in unmarshalling and marshalling xml schema and consuming a web service

Tags: java, xml, web-services

I have to unmarshall an xml schema and then have to create a client to access a web service(whose schema it is). I have learned to generate java classes using 'xjc' command. i am clueless how to proceed. I am trying to find a webservice available online to get its schema, and then unmarshall it and then create a client object to unmarshall and use it. i have really tried to find on the internet but am not able to do so.

in some of the questions asked here about free web - services to play with, "http://www.programmableweb.com/" has been suggested but i cud not locate a webservice to consume there.
please can anyone tell me the step by step process for this.

Comment: this site has more of APIs. please also suggest about how to find the webservise.

Comment: any help is more than appreciated. need a website to use sample xmls from